# True and False value does not change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a code like this:

```
public IActionResult Urgent(TodoTable t)
{
    var Task = db.TodoTables.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == t.Id);
    Task!.Urgent = t.Urgent; // If the value is True it will change to False and if False it will change to True.
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And `Index.cshtml`:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/TodoTables/Urgent/@item.Id">@(item.Urgent ? "Unurgent" : "Urgent")</a>
```

If the Urgent value in the database is `True`, it will be `False`, and if `False`, it will be `True`. But I could not do this on the Controller side. Only `True` becomes `False`, then does not become `True` again.

How can I do that?

Comment: Negate the value of `Task.Urgent`. `Task.Urgent = !Task.Urgent;` Is this your requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try replacing your code like this?

```
Task.Urgent = !Task.Urgent;
```